# How to find start date of a week

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a date. I have to identify date of the monday in the week which my date lies.

Comment: `sql-server` or `mysql`? Tag your question properly.

Comment: i suppose it would also make a difference how you classify which day belongs to which week - ie, what day does your week start on?

Comment: my week starts with monday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    SET DATEFIRST 1
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'2012-01-01'),'2012-01-01')
```

Comment: **Bravo!!** Short and regional independent!

Answer (score 3):

**MSSQL**

```
 SELECT CONVERT(varchar,DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()) /7*7, 0),100) AS weekstart
```

**MySql**

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(date)) +1 DAY) AS weekStart
```

Comment: The MSSQL one is rather opaque.If I saw this in production code, I'd rewrite it to be a little more obvious.

Comment: I second the opinion of @BenThul

Comment: @BenThul never the less it is the best solution. However converting it to varchar is a huge mistake. The date is no longer a date. This is the only answer that doesn't rely on DATEFIRST.

Comment: I undeleted my answer because I realized it was correct. It is much like yours, just a bit shorter.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the `@@DATEFIRST`. To get the start of the week which in your case is a Monday:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
DECLARE @ThisDate DATE = GETDATE()
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @ThisDate), @ThisDate)
```

Comment: My week starts with monday

Comment: when we are trying with sunday it will make problem. i have to get monday before that. try this select dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, '2012-01-01'), 0).

Comment: datefirst is not used in selection statement SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2012-01-01'), '2012-01-01') still give me error

Comment: I always avoid DATEFIRST. When used in functions you need to set it every time you call that function. If you forget to set DATEFIRST before using it, it will often give different result on a different server with different default values - as you already experienced here. There is ALWAYS a better workaround

Comment: it is giving answer 2012-01-01 instead of 2011-12-26

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(curdate()) - 0 DAY)
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#c8178

Answer (score 2):

Takes the difference between epoch (day 0) and the date.

Divide that number by 7 and round off(automatic rounding when working with integers) this will be the number of weeks to add to day 0

```
SELECT dateadd(week, datediff(d, 0, getdate())/7, 0)
```

Comment: @Giosco there was a bug in my calculation. It has been corrected. Now the week starts on monday instead of sunday. It will not depend of DATEFIRST which i think is a big mistake. If you have this in a function, you wil lbe forced to set DATEFIRST every time you call the function.

Comment: @SQLPolice my week starts on monday. Just went through my original answer and realized that there was no bugs.

Comment: Yes, that's now a correct solution. The "0" (2nd operand in `datediff`) means Jan 1, 1900 - and by incident, **the 20th century started on a monday.** (which was cool ;) ) So you basically calculate the number of full weeks since 1900-01-01, and you add these weeks to Monday, Jan 1, 1900 . Thus, you get the last monday.